# The getter 'password' isn't defined for the type 'Icons'

Tags: flutter, dart, icons

The icons I selected appear to be undefined even though they are in the class. What is the reason for this?

```
Icon(
    Icons.password,
    color: iconColor,
    )
```

[image]

Comment: Are the other icons wrorking??

Comment: Password and some icons are not working and some are working eg Icons.home is working

Comment: What flutter version do you have? Check it with `flutter doctor`.

Comment: I added above..

Comment: flutter doctor --android-licenses // run this and accept the license

Comment: Flutter version 2.1.0-13.0.pre.160

Comment: I solved this problem, it has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

> Open your cmd or android studio terminal and type[flutter doctor, then flutter doctor --android-licenses] and accept all of the licenses that terminal suggest you.

Answer (score 0):

Check if in your `pubspec.yaml` the section `uses-material-design` is set to  true.

After seeing your `flutter doctor` output: try upgrading your version by using `flutter upgrade`. Then, run `flutter clean` and then `flutter run` in terminal.

Comment: uses-material-design: true
already so.

Comment: I solved this problem, it has nothing to do with it.

Comment: How did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use material_design_icons_flutter package.

```
import 'package:material_design_icons_flutter/material_design_icons_flutter.dart';

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new IconButton(
      // Use the MdiIcons class for the IconData
      icon: new Icon(MdiIcons.sword),
      onPressed: () { print('Using the sword'); }
     );
  }
}
```